# Are ten 2W speakers as loud as two 10W speakers?

Tags: frequency, speakers, decibel

If all things are the same (e.g. total magnet weight, manufacturer, cone material) and I have two 10W speakers as compared to ten 2W speakers would the decibel level be the same?

Comment: Depends on what's driving them and the distance, but theoretically yes

Comment: Well, theoretically you can make two speakers work in anti-phase, so they will produce silence at full power.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can I use "full power silence" as a trademark for a product I'm bound to start inventing over drinks tonight?

Comment: @Asmyldof Yes.. For a share :) Actually, I wanted to put a smiley in the end of the previous comment, but then realized that it is serious.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's quiet serious.

Comment: This is actually more of a [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) question, not electrical engineering.

Comment: BTW, you should probably not speak of “2 W / 10 W speakers” but of 7 identical speakers with unspecified ratings, and just say you drive either ten of them with 2 W each or two of them with 10 W each. A speaker's power rating is a somewhat fuzzy specification.

Comment: If you are using lots of little speakers you can create a phased array to focus the energy into a smaller area - making it louder in that spot. http://hackaday.com/2014/04/14/steering-sound-with-phased-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key parameter that needs to be the same is the *efficiency* of the speakers, in terms of electrical power in to acoustic power out. The other things you list (magnet weight, cone material, etc.) are only indirect indicators of efficiency, and there are many other parameters that would apply as well.

Comment: And even if the "total magnet weight, manufacturer, cone material" were the same, a smaller cone area alone is going to change the performance characteristics and resulting output. Have a look at [Thiele-Small Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiele/Small) for the multitude of variables used to represent speaker characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

If *all* else is the same then, yes, the power output and decibel level would be the same.

However, it's more likely that the physical arrangement of the speakers would *not* be the same, leading to either a perceptual difference or an actual measured difference due to differences in distance from source to sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Sound is always measured at a distance from the speakers. Why? the inverse square law. The intensity of observed radiation is inversely proportional to the square of the distance between the source and the observer. The practical result of this is that the best way to configure the speakers depends on desired coverage and placement as well.